# Why do these similar programs have different outcomes?

Tags: prolog

I was doing an exercise that asked to implement `from_to/3`, where you give two numbers as the first two arguments and Prolog gives you a list of everything between them as result. For example: `from_to(1,5,R)` would give `R=[1,2,3,4,5]`.

I wrote the following program:

```
fromto(N, O, []):-
    N >= O.
fromto(N, O, [N|TailResult]):-
    O > N,
    O1 is O-1,
    fromto(N, O1, TailResult).
```

With query `fromto(3,8,R)` it returns a list of five 3's. Not good.
The correct way to handle it would be:

```
from_to(N, O, []) :- 
    N > O.
from_to(N, O, [N|TailResult]) :- 
    N =< O, 
    N1 is N + 1, 
    from_to(N1, O, TailResult).
```

This gives the `list 3,4,5,6,7,8` as intended.

My question is how this works. The programs differ only in that I worked down from top to bottom with O and the correct one works upwards by adding to N. Yet the results are totally different.
Does anyone know what causes this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in your first attempt first argument-N does not change only O change, and you place N in the list recursively so all you're gonna see is a list of N's.

If you want to keep this approach you have to place each time O in the list:

```
fromto(N, O, []):-
    N > O.
fromto(N, O, L):-
    O >= N,
    O1 is O-1,
    fromto(N, O1, L2),
    append(L2,[O],L).
```

The problem with this implementation is that you need to use `append/3`in order to place in right order else you will get the inverse list. This is not so efficient because every time you need to add an element in the list you need to traverse all the list and place it at the ende which gives an additional overhead.

EXAMPLE:

```
?- fromto(3,8,L).
L = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] ;
false.
```

Also you could use DCG as suggested by @false:

```
from_to(N,N) -->[N].
from_to(N,O) --> [N],{N<O, N1 is N+1},from_to(N1,O).

final_solution(N,O,L):- phrase(from_to(N,O),L).
```

And the other way (decreasing O instead of N):

```
from_to(N,N) -->[N].
from_to(N,O) --> {N<O, O1 is O-1},from_to(N,O1),[O].

final_solution(N,O,L):- phrase(from_to(N,O),L).
```

Now the two ways of solving are very similar just change the order of the second clause.

Comment: Instead of using `append/3` it would be more insightful to formulate the two approaches using [tag:dcg]-notation.